# Did President Carter state that the United States had developed "an invisible plane"?

Tags: united-states, aviation

The book [The Presidents and UFOs: A Secret History from FDR to Obama](https://books.google.com/books?id=0cmMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22invisible%22%20%22plane%22%20%22stealth%22%20carter&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii_oS72crcAhUQEawKHba3B3MQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22invisible%22%20%22plane%22%20%22stealth%22%20carter&f=false) says:

> Prior to the 1980 election Carter had stated in a news conference that the U.S. had developed “an invisible plane” which at the time was the highly classified stealth program.

I'm skeptical since this is a UFO book.  However, the 26 August 1980 [Tampa Bay Times](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/79470789/) says:

> The Democratic administration, countering charges of national military weakness, responds with rhetoric of its own and lets it be known we have developed a wondrous new weapon, an "invisible plane" code-named "stealth" whose configuration defies enemy radar.

Also, the [Congressional Record](https://books.google.com/books?id=AtkhIwG79CwC&q=%22by%20the%20Republicans%20of%20jeopardizing%20national%20security%20for%20political%20gain%20when%20he%20disclosed%20the%20%E2%80%9Cinvisible%20plane%E2%80%9D%20program%22&dq=%22by%20the%20Republicans%20of%20jeopardizing%20national%20security%20for%20political%20gain%20when%20he%20disclosed%20the%20%E2%80%9Cinvisible%20plane%E2%80%9D%20program%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9xoCx38rcAhUHcq0KHXMgDJcQ6AEIJzAA) says:

> President Carter was accused by the Republicans of jeopardizing national security for political gain when he disclosed the “invisible plane” program.

My question is did President Carter use the exact words "invisible plane" to characterize a US military plane?

Comment: Given that you found confirmation in two non-UFO sources, why are you still skeptical about it?

Comment: @Fizz I want to know if it is an exact quote of the President himself (as opposed to a paraphrase, or a quote from someone else in his administration).

Comment: Why is that an interesting question? It's matter of PR terminology, it's not like he meant it literally.

Comment: @Fizz Not everybody will agree what questions are interesting.  I think it's of historical interest how stealth planes were characterized.

Comment: @Fizz Right, this also says "Defense officials admitted Thursday that they revealed the general nature of the so-called "invisible-bomber" program over the objections of top Air Force generals, who argued that any disclosure of the top-secret program would harm it seriously." https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/120044141/ so the UFO reference is wrong about Carter disclosing at a news conference.

Comment: [WaPo mentions](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/08/14/carter-to-support-new-us-bomber/d449b8bf-5f2f-4a78-829e-148f5c654c1d/?utm_term=.ac8cb5c9837e) that Carter's staff had prepared some speech notes possibly covering "stealth" as well, but it's not clear if Carter ever gave that (part of the) speech. Given that that article is from Aug 14, I guess Carter didn't do it and let Brown do the disclosure instead.

Comment: The speech in question is on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyRhTDe7gtM but it's an hour long :-( If you have the patience...

Comment: Brown's speech on the 22nd was also televised according to https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/09/06/stealth-disclosure-defended-against-reckless-distortions/a0c6d418-536d-45de-be90-454afb2343f6/?utm_term=.838e2e8693c7 but it's gonna be harder to find, and you don't seem to want to know what the administration said, only Carter himself.

Comment: But Carter wrote a letter to congress on the matter https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/09/21/carter-orders-own-stealth-leak-probe/7d22ac26-6116-485a-9f60-fe9a9db9eb57/?utm_term=.798edf2e2d00 I could not yet find the full text.

Comment: How many times did Trump say the F-35 was invisible n 2018?

Answer (score 6):

I found an [interview with Carter published in 1999](https://nsarchive2.gwu.edu/coldwar/interviews/episode-18/carter2.html); it's not clear to me when the interview was actually taken, but it certainly was after 1990 because he mentinoed the Gulf War. Anyway, in this interview Carter said:

> And the fact that we developed... and I even announced, during my last year in office, that we had developed the technology for the Stealth aircraft, which makes them totally impervious to any sort of defense - **there's no way to see them in the sky with radar** - and so I don't think there's any doubt about that.

It seems a little odd he says he announced it, when by more detailed accounts it was Harold Brown, his secretary of defence, [who did it, on Aug 22, 1980](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/09/06/stealth-disclosure-defended-against-reckless-distortions/a0c6d418-536d-45de-be90-454afb2343f6/?utm_term=.6a99f90f2fab). Carter probably meant his administration by "I".

Anyway, in the interview Carter says something that's reasonably close to "invisible by radar", so not just "invisible". For what it's worth, the press coverage at the time of disclosure used similar terminology, such as ["radar-invisible plane"](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP92B00478R000800340047-6.pdf) (Washington Post headline) or ["virtually invisible aircraft"](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP92B00478R000800340037-7.pdf) in the Armed Forces Journal. The more official term "Stealth" was also employed both by Carter (in the above snippet) and by the press of the time.

The 1980 disclosure created a political scandal at the time, after Reagan (and others) attacked it. Carter was forced to defend Brown's disclosure [in a letter to Congress](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/09/21/carter-orders-own-stealth-leak-probe/7d22ac26-6116-485a-9f60-fe9a9db9eb57/?utm_term=.d84a72cfaf50), so in this sense Carter did get more personally involved.

Another interesting twist is that (as DavePhD discovered) [the congressional investigation into the leaks](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP92B00478R000800340001-6.pdf) concluded that the aforementiond Armed Forces Journal article was pushed through and partly conveived by undersectrary William Perry in collaboration with the Journal's editor, who had already obtained a lot of relevant information from unclassfied sources, but had delayed publishing them at Perry's request. The Journal article was published on purpose just before Brown's press conference (and in fact mentions the imminence of Brown's announcement).

Comment: It was really announced two days earlier on 20 August 1980 when the September issue of Armed Forces Journal was released, which quoted defense official.  The Journal said "Since early 1978, the United States has been test flying several versions of virtually invisible new airplanes, both in manned and unmanned versions" and that "planes are virtually invisible to air-defense radars, to infrared or other electronic or acoustic detection systems" .  Then many papers on the 21st had titles like "invisible planes" quoting from the Journal https://newspaperarchive.com/kenosha-news-aug-21-1980-p-5/

Comment: @DavePhD: If the official was not named (in AFJ) that sounds more like a leak which prompted the "official" announcement. I'm not much inclined to sign up for that newspaper archive myself to check the details myself (Clearly it wasn't Carter himself who announced it)... CS Monitor  says "Both Brown and Perry insist that the Stealth program was shrouded in the deepest secrecy until they revealed it Aug. 22."

Comment: This is the actual AFJ article https://books.google.com/books?id=Dj9VAAAAYAAJ&q=invisible+new+plane&dq=invisible+new+plane&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL5qG19MvcAhVlu1kKHQ8kAwUQ6AEIKTAA Title "US Has Been Flying Virtually Invisible Aircraft for Over Two Years Several Tactical Versions Are In Production".  A later issue in the same volume says that on 18 August Under Secretary of defense William Perry provided the editor a personal update on the program, and the article was based on that.

Comment: Under Secretary Perry insisted on 18 August that Schemmer (the editor) publish the information by 21 August, even though Schemmer objected to publishing the information at all.  https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP92B00478R000800340001-6.pdf

Comment: This is a CIA copy of the AFJ article https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP92B00478R000800340037-7.pdf

Comment: @DavePhD: Interesting; I didn't have the patience to get to the findings of the leaks investigation committee. I'm not sure how I could improve the core of my answer with that though...

Comment: Yes, everything leads to the conclusion that it wasn't Carter directly, and only news media used terms like "invisible plane", "invisible aircraft", "invisible bomber".  I like the part of the AFJ article that discusses a Washington rumor "that the Pentagon invented 'transparent' paint to make airplanes invisible".

Comment: I'd also point out that it's entirely possible that the military just used "invisible" as shorthand.  Since the only way you are going to take one of those aircraft out is via systems that use radar, being able to physically see it with human eyeballs at any particular time is irrelevant to the more practical considerations.

Comment: There's a typo in the first line ("mentinoed" instead of "mentioned").